# Not able to download the content of the web site

Tags: wget, download

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. I opened [this website](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072520426) in my browser. The site starts downloading and displaying previews of a book on the same page.

I'd like to download the book displayed on the page to my system's hard drive.
If I use `wget`, it's downloading only the page but not the book. Here's the command I'm trying, please check for clarity by opening the URL in browser and then using `wget`.

```
$ wget http://www.amazon.com/gp/reader/0072520426/ref=sib_dp_ptu#reader-link
```

When you open via a web browser, the book will start downloading and displaying on the page. How can I download the book to my hard disk. There are no options on the page for downloading either.

Answer (score 0):

The book is a succession of images as can be seen in the developer tab (or dev tools or source page, however you like to call it) and you might need to use the recursive method to download it all (that if the server allows it).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But please can you say something more on what that recursive method is? I am hearing it for the 1st time

Comment: recursive is to download everything under a determinated path. It can be used with the `-R` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [`httrack`](http://www.httrack.com/) for downloading/mirroring web content from a site.

```
$ httrack http://2011.example.com -K -w -O . -%v --robots=0 -c1 %e0
```

After it runs you're left with a directory structure that's local and browseable. For example:

```
$ ls -l
total 304
-rw-r--r--  1 saml saml   4243 Aug 17 10:20 backblue.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 saml saml    828 Aug 17 10:20 fade.gif
drwx------  3 saml saml   4096 Aug 17 10:20 hts-cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 saml saml    233 Aug 17 10:20 hts-in_progress.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 saml saml   1517 Aug 17 10:20 hts-log.txt
-rw-------  1 saml saml 271920 Aug 17 10:22 hts-nohup.out
-rw-r--r--  1 saml saml   5141 Aug 17 10:20 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 10 saml saml   4096 Aug 17 10:21 2011.example.com
```

As it downloads you'll see the following type of output:

```
Bytes saved:    21,89KiB           Links scanned:   12/45 (+4)
Time:   2s                         Files written:   4
Transfer rate:  2,65KiB/s (2,65KiB/s)  Files updated:   1
Active connections:     1          Errors:  7

Current job: parsing HTML file (57%)
 request -  2011.example.com/cgi-bin/hostnames.pl   0B /    8,00KiB
```

It can be backgrounded and/or aborted and later resumed. This is just the tip of the iceberg in terms of it's features. There is also a GUI for both setting up a download and monitoring it as it progresses.

There is extensive documentation on the [`httrack` website](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html) and by googling.